# sorting table data based on another table by sum of a value

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if its possible to sort a table based on the sums of values in another table. The issue im facing is the following: im running this query on my database:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT thread_id, SUM(upvoted) AS upvoted FROM upvotes GROUP BY thread_id ORDER BY upvoted LIMIT :start, {$number_threads}";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':start', (int) $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Thereafter im making this while loop

```
while($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // do something with the following variables
    $result['thread_id'];
    $result['thread_content'];
    $result['thread_ownerid'];                        
}
```

But the columns thread_id, thread_content and thread_ownerid do not exist inside the table upvotes. They only exist inside a table called threads. The most straightforward solution to this problem is joining. However, the problem with joining is that the values in the table upvotes are all non-unique. so a thread_id that is unique in threads can for instance be present in 5432 rows with corresponding -1 en 1 values in the column upvoted in the table upvotes.

My idea to go around this problem is: Make an array/dictionary with indices/keys that link the thread_id with the sum of all its upvotes and then join this array/dict with the table threads.

This is one theoretical way of accesing the desired variables, but any way that allows me to acces them will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance for investing time in my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, but you have to add this value as a new column in your select result like this:

```
select a.id,a.other,
        (select count(*) 
         FROM table2 AS B 
         WHERE b.id=a.id) AS c
FROM table1  AS a
ORDER BY c;
```

The C value would be the count (or sum) of some values in other table

Comment: Thanks, it does indeed fetch the data in the desired order but i run into this new problem: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().

Comment: first using fetch all on your query and then looping through the dict that will be generated gets me in trouble with queries that im running within the while loop

Comment: allright its a bit buggy but closeCursor(); seems to fix the issue! Thanks a lot for answering my question